# How do I set the number of arrivals?

Tags: anylogic

I'm new to anylogic and I have a question, how do I solve this: supply of 30 materials every 10 minutes.

runtime: 5 hours.

Comment: Hi Maria Cristina. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what have you already did? What have you tried to solve this problem? Even if the early solution doesn't work, it's OK, because you learn for that a lot. Kind regards... P.S.: There was a discussion about homework assignments here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

30 materials every 10 minutes means 3 materials per minute... in anylogic a material is defined as an agent.

you can generate agents in many different ways, the most typical is using the source from the process modeling library in which you put as a rate 3 per minute

Note that this means that your arrivals will follow a poisson distribution...which means you won't get exactly 3 materials every minute, but if you run for 5 hours, the average will be close to that

if you want exactly 30 materials every 10 minutes, you can use arrivals defined by interarrival time, with intervals of 20 seconds